Fitting deadbolt strike with plate over plate-less one on a hollow metal door
I am trying to replace a deadbolt lock on my door (hollow metal one). The old lock is Mul-T-lock with a strike that doesn't have a plate (see photo). The new lock's strike is a standard in that it does have a plate.
Questions:

I assume it is OK to just drill two holes into the door to match the strike plate holes?
I think there is enough gap between the door and the frame to let strike stay on top of the door's surface (instead of being flush with it). But in case I do need to make it flush, what is the right way to "chisel" that area to provide space for the plate? Also, apart from purely aesthetic considerations, are there any problems with the plate not being flush?
Finally, what would be the right way to screw the plate into such a door?

Any help is appreciated! :-)


Many lock manufacturers make it an option to remove the plate and just use the barrel. Look at the back of the plate . There may be small tabs that can be bent out and the plate slides off.
